# How to style the value of different types of input widgets through code?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a form which contains multiple input widgets like textbox, dropdown, textarea, suggestbox, radiogroup and multiselect etc

The input widgets are by default in disabled state.

When I click on a button all of them get enabled. 
I would also like their text-color to change when I click on that button.

Note: I dont want to change the widget's label color. Only the value color.

How to do it in code for each? If you could give one example for each widget i.e textbox, dropdown, multiselect,radigroup etc

Looking for a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to change your text box text red when you click the button. add a class to your styles tab like

```
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

then say you have text box called textbox1 in the onclick event of your button put the following code:

```
widget.root.descendants.textbox1.styles = ['red'];
```

same for all the other types

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea I was testing with TextBox and worked but with TextAreas the Input or Value did not change, as well as the other multiselect and radioGroup options it did not take the css as expected.

When you click on the text box and from the CSS Page Style you start typing "." you will find different options for the widget selected. Using TextBox there is an Input option so you create a Global Style like this one.

```
    .color Input{
          color:teal;              
                 }
```

This will change the Input of the TextBox, the same as if you do with Label, just use the same css class just change the option you want to modify. `.color Label {}`.

Also to apply the change to the widget just create a function like this one.

```
function textBoxColorChange() {

  app.pages.NewPage.descendants.TextArea1.styles = ["color"];

}
```

And create an OnClick event to a button to make the change.

With the other widgets I don't have the time to keep testing but I hope this helps to get the idea. Greetings.